# Put text file to certain directory

Tags: python

I would like to save my text file to some certain directory but have an error **object of type 'file' has no len()** after running the code.

Here is my code, please check it out to find the bug for me. Thank you very much. (I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7)

```
import datetime

import os.path

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'):

    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)


with open(timeStamped('Log.txt'),'w') as outf:

    path = 'c:/1/test'

    os.path.join(path,outf)
```

Comment: try `os.path.join(path,timeStamped('Log.txt'))`. You are trying to join a string and a file object. Internally its calling `len` on both arguments, which it assumes are strings.

Comment: You're trying to `os.path.join` a string and a file

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried your solution out, and the error gone. But new question comes out, I checked out the directory 'c:/1/test', but did not see the text file I created. Any advice about it?